# Solving a tricky 4th order PDE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem, delay-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following linear PDE, that is fourth order in space and second order in time:

$$
\text{(PDE):} \hspace{5mm} \frac{\partial^4 y}{\partial x^4} + \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} - \lambda e^{i\omega t}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = 0 
$$

Subject to initial and boundary conditions:

$$
\hspace{-8.5mm}\text{(IC):} \hspace{5mm} 0 = y(x, 0) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x, 0) \\
\hspace{-11mm}\text{(BC1):} \hspace{5mm} 0 = y(0, t) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(0, t) \\
\hspace{-4mm}\text{(BC2):} \hspace{5mm} 0= \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}(1, t) = \frac{\partial^3 y}{\partial x^3}(1, t)
$$

Here $\lambda$ is a positive parameter and the domain for this system is: $x\in[0, 1]$, $t\in[0, \infty)$.

I have attempted many different approaches for solving this system analytically but haven't been able to make much progress. I believe that no seperable solution exists. I have tried playing around with integral transform methods, but for example a Laplace transform leads to a delay-like differential equation that seems harder to solve:
$$
0 = \frac{d^4Y}{dx^4}(x, s) + s^2Y(x, s) - \lambda\frac{d^2Y}{dx^2}(x, s-i\omega)
$$

I wanted to know if anyone had experience in solving a system like this and what approaches (if any) may actually yield analytical progress. Any insight/help would be very much appreciated. In particular, I am not aware if this problem would fall under the scope of some complex analytic methods.

For context, this is a dimensionless system modelling a clamped-free, elastic-magnetic beam deforming under an oscillatory magnetic field. Since the equation is linear, the presence of the $e^{i\omega t}$ term was included in the usual way where the real part is being assumed and would be taken after solving the system.

Comment: @Gonçalo correct me if I'm wrong but, I believe that my boundary conditions mean that no solution like this will work. In particular, the condition y(x=0, t) = 0 would render any solution like this to be the zero solution. I think that a similar thing happens for any seperable ansatz, including seeking any normal mode like solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, from what I've read Mathieu functions are pretty hard to use in any analytic way not sure progress from here will be much easier! Thanks for the suggestion though, will explore it a bit more and see if I can find anything.

Comment: @Gonçalo when $\lambda=0$ this becomes the standard beam equation which does emit normal mode solutions: $y(x,t) = f(x)e^{i\Omega t}$. I wanted to study the effect of magnetic inclusion so do not want to just ignore this term. I was wondering if the leading order problem in small $\omega$ (slow oscillations). Would be any easier to solve. The problem then reduces to:
$$
0 = \frac{\partial^4 y}{\partial x^4} + \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} - \lambda\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}
$$
This problem seems a lot simpler but again I haven't found anything that works - do you have any ideas?